# Visual Studio 2013 Single-File Mode?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, code-behind

I am fairly new to using VS 2013, but I had quite a bit of time in on 2010 version. In VS 2010, working with ASP.NET, I could choose to use a "single file" method instead of the "code-behind" option. This is where the VB code could reside at the top of a page, then the scripting below. 
I detest having separate files for code and content, but I cannot find the option in VS 2013 to disable code-behind mode. Did they do away wit this feature?

TIA

Comment: I think it's no more present in VS2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is only available for websites not web applications, go to File->New->Website and create a new website, then you can choose to have the code behind on the same page or separate page when you are adding new pages.

*Keep in mind there are differences between a website and a web application, please investigate further before choosing which project type is suitable for you.*

Comment: Thank you, I did look that up on MSDN and it explains it clear as day, I just don't see why that information is not a little more accessible.